# How to reduce XML string length for storing in DB?

Tags: c#, xml, string-length

I have XLM that looks like that (length 278 characters):

```
<AppList>
  <App>
    <Info1>Value 1</Info1>
    <Info2>Value 2</Info2>
    <Info3>Value 3</Info3>
    <AppList>
      <App>
        <Info1>Value 4</Info1>
        <Info2>Value 5</Info2>
        <Info3>Value 6</Info3>
      </App>
    </AppList>
  </App>
</AppList>
```

For storing in DB I want it to look like that (length 192 characters):

```
<AppList><App><Info1>Value 1</Info1><Info2>Value 2</Info2><Info3>Value 3</Info3><AppList><App><Info1>Value 4</Info1><Info2>Value 5</Info2><Info3>Value 6</Info3></App></AppList></App></AppList>
```

In Notepad++ they have something like `Linearize XML`, which does the work.
Is there any way to do that programmatically in C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#/XSLT: Linearizing XML partially working code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131542/c-xslt-linearizing-xml-partially-working-code)

Comment: @MohitShrivastava the suggested duplicate has no good answer

Comment: `Regex.Replace(xmlString, @">\s+<", "><")`.  There may be some edge cases that could be problematic.

Comment: Removing `Line-feeds` is not an option? `xmlString = xmlString.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, xmlString)`

Comment: On a side note: it doesn't mean because you can store xml (or other serialized objects) in a relational database that you should. Always ask yourself what the added benefit is. Serialization / deserialization of relational data isn't overly expensive these days.

Comment: Read it calmly @Toshi Even the partial working code is nicer and OP can improve it to make it more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider below methods.

1. With reference to [the duplicated content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131542/c-xslt-linearizing-xml-partially-working-code), you can do it in C#.
2. [Just Compress text-to-text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17993002/361100): there's several methods to compress texts. Of course, it is hard to do string search afterwards.
3. [Use XML support in SQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345115(v=sql.90).aspx): most of SQL database stores XML in compressed manner natively. Or [this article](http://aboutsqlserver.com/2015/04/07/compressing-lob-xml-data-in-the-database/) could be helpful also.
4. [Describe in Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/814027/361100): XML is verbose than json expression in general. XML and json both are tree structure so 1:1 conversion is possible.